# location.reload() gives an alert to retry to submit data

Tags: jquery, struts2, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jQuery UI for opening the popup, I wanted to refresh the parent window once the window is closed.

In jQuery the code is

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function(){
   location.reload();
});
```

Then the page appears with the below window. The URL is https. How I can avoid this.

[image]

Thank you for help in advance, please let me know if any additional information required.

Comment: try reloading with window.location.href=window.location.href

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666159/reloading-page-through-javascript-avoid-the-postback-warning

Comment: In the answer for url Michal given boolean within reload() is new, will that help avoid that window?

Comment: No read other answers and comments :) I think that you will eventualy have to do manual redirect to the page that opened your popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my situation I have removed the reload() option and used jQuery .load function.

```
("#refreshDiv").load("actionName #refreshDiv");
```

it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you. And you call your function like this `reloadPage();`

```
 function reloadPage()
 {
 window.location.reload()
 }
```

Comment: how this is different from location.reload()